# VS2013 code coverage doesn't find any XUnit tests

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage, xunit

When I go to Test > Analyze Code coverage > All Tests, the output is "0 found". How do I get Visual Studio 2013 to pick up my XUnit tests?

This shows up in the output window the first time I try (Output > Tests).

> ------ Discover test started ------
>
> NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
>
> NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished
>
> ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.4240424) ==========

If I try a second time, the output window is blank.

Am I supposed to look somewhere else?

I'm using ReSharper to run my tests. ReSharper works, but VS's Test > Run all Tests doesn't find any tests either.

Comment: Did you install the xUnit.NET add on? If not, VS is only capable of finding MSTest and NUnit test cases.

Comment: What plugin? xunit.net runner is deprecated

Comment: Have you applied the NuGet package?http://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-vs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Lex Li, I installed the NuGet package xunit.runner.visualstudio, which resolved the issue